# Search link in Textarea from Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, search, hyperlink

I've a very simple question. I just want to search if there's any link containing in the textarea.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function valid()
{
var txtt=document.forms["forma"]["txtarea"].value;
var ss=txtt.search("href");
if (ss == "0"){
alert("You've link in your textarea! We don't allow that");
return false;
}
}
</script>

<form action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return valid()" name="forma">
<textarea name="txtarea"></textarea>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Sample data. I want above to not to be passed and return false.

```
 Hi! I bookmarked your site http://www.myspamdata.com
```

or

```
<a href="http://myspam.com">My spam link</a>
```

Comment: You need to enforce this restriction on the server. Spam bots do not execute JavaScript at all.

Comment: @ThiefMaster - while this may be good advice, it's unwise to underestimate spambots!

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution is sufficient for your problem:

```
var txtt=document.forms["forma"]["txtarea"].value
var ss=txtt.search('http://');
if(ss != -1) {
    alert("...");
    return false;
}
```

You just look for the string "http://". But there is one problem with this generally solution. You can easily by pass such Javascript "protections". So you need to check for links in the server code too and reject them.

Comment: Thank you, this works. What actually my mistake was that I was doing it if ss == "0". I didn't know this can be whatever if found. :D

Comment: Well, I should blog about StackOverFlow at Khapay.com. Stack said "Vote Up requires 15 reputation
(click on this box to dismiss)"

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Regex like this :

`var regex = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;`

and validate your input string against it to see if there are any such links specified.

For example, search for it using:

```
var regex = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
var exists = text.search(regex);
```

Comment: Your code is actually good looking but this isn't working. You need to work on it.

Comment: when you say it isn't working, what is not working, and how did you ues it?

Comment: I am simply putting it here var ss=txtt.search("/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/i");

Comment: Use it like this : `var ss=txtt.search(/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig);` .I have also added it to my answer.

Comment: And if the spambot doesn't execute javascript, and/or just puts in "copy/past www.myspamsite.com into your address bar"?

Comment: So what would you suggest to try?